# Can we use the sched_setscheduler() system call to assign a process to the stop scheduler?

Tags: linux-kernel

I was trying to play around with the kernel schedulers, and since the /kernel/sched/stop_task.c stop scheduler is the simplest, I wanted to try assigning a user space process to it to better understand the kernel scheduling code.

However, it seems that include/uapi/linux/sched.h does not have a SCHED_STOP (or similar) flag that I would be able to use to get the int to pass to sched_setscheduler(). Is there some way for me to use this system call to assign a task to the stop scheduler?

Just wondering about this.

Thanks.

Comment: "stop scheduler"? https://lwn.net/Articles/805317/ that article might have all the answers.

Comment: Thanks. For posterity, the linked article indicates that the stop scheduler can only be used *internally* be the kernel, due to the fact that it can be preempt everything and never be preempted by anything, so the kernel developers didn't want it to be abused from user space.